# What is alternative for onload for <a>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, onload

I have this HTML:

```
<a onmouseover="coverLookout(this,0)" style="width:100%;overflow:hidden" href="#jtCr4NsVySc" class="youtube">
    <img id="video_642" style="width:100%;margin-left:0;max-width:100%;visibility:visible" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/jtCr4NsVySc/mqdefault.jpg">
    <span></span>
</a>
```

And js:

```
var yt=new Array('maxresdefault.jpg','mqdefault.jpg');
var coverLookout = function(block,i){
    console.log(i);
    var code=$(block).attr('href').toString().substr(1);
    var url = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + code + "/" + yt[i];
    $(function($){
        $.ajax({
            url: "function_js.php?page=check_img",
            data: {"url":url},
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
                if(response=="200"){
                    $(block).find("img").attr('src',url);return;
                }else{
                    coverLookout(block,++i);
                }
            }
        });
    });
};
```

How can I use `coverLookout` function while `*a*` is loading instead of `onmouseover`? `*A*` `onload` doesn't work because `onload` I can use only with `*body*`. But how do `onload` for other tags?

Comment: do you mean when the link load(ie when page loads) call the another function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

onload Function works only with `<body>` so after document loading (under `$(document).ready()` function collect all `a` tags and call the function based on their index.

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
coverLookout(els[i],i);
 }
```

Comment: I have other links on page. So how I can get all links with 'youtube' class?

Comment: beter to filter only youtube class like var els = $(".youtube");

Comment: like this: var els = $(".youtube").getElementsByTagName("a"); Or just els = $(".youtube");

Comment: just var els = $(".youtube"); in jquery

Comment: var els = $(".youtube"); It takes only first element

Comment: sorry. try with var els=document.getElementsByClassName("youtube");

Answer (score 3):

> A onload doesn't work because onload I can use only with body. But how do onload for other tags?

No, it works for elements that have a `load` event. `a` doesn't have a load event because it never has something to load. All `a` content is inline. `load` relates to things like images and scripts and stylesheets and such, that load a separate resource.

`img` has a `load` event, if you're talking about the **image** inside the link loading. You have to be sure to hook the event *before* setting the `img` source (the `onload` attribute works), or check the `complete` flag on the element if hooking the event later to see if it's already done.

---

From the comments below, it sounds like you want to change the `img`'s source when the link is clicked. You can do that like this:

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('video_642').src = '/new/src/here.png' ...
```

...or as you're using jQuery, this will handle all `youtube` links:

```
$("a.youtube").click(function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", "/new/src/here.png");
});
```

But the user may not see it, because when the link is followed, the browser tears down the page right away. You can improve the chances your user will see it if you make sure it's already in cache, by putting it on your page somewhere but hidden:

```
<img style="display: none" src="/new/src/here.png">
```

...so the browser has it in cache to display it before tearing down the page.

---

> I want to while page is loading src in img will be changed by script

You mean when the page these links are on is loading? Okay. This would go in a `script` tag at the end of the `body` (just before the closing `</body>` element:

```
// Find all images within a.youtube links and change their `src`
$("a.youtube img").each(function() {
    var img = $(this);

    // Save current src so we can put it back later
    img.attr("data-real-src", this.src);

    // Set new source        
    this.src = "/new/src/here.png";
});

// Then when the page is done loading...
$(window).on("load", function() {
    // Restore the original `src` values on the images
    $("img[data-real-src]").each(function() {
        var img = $(this);
        img.attr("src", img.attr("data-real-src")).removeAttr("data-real-src");
    });
});
```

Comment: So, how can I make function while link is loading?

Comment: @Masiama: "link is loading" doesn't make any sense. The link is there as soon as the page is shown. Do you mean you want to do something when the user *follows* the link? Because if so, unless the link uses `target` to open a new window, while you can run code when the link is clicked, the page is torn down immediately afterward so the user wouldn't see anything you did (if you did something they could see).

Comment: I want to while page is loading src on a will be replaced

Comment: @Masiama: `a` elements *don't have* a `src` property (or attribute).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think that was 'page source', can't be sure though. OP, are you saying you want to simply replace the anchor on page load?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have img in a and ing has src

Comment: @oGeez Yes, I want to replace img src!

Comment: @Masiama: I've updated the answer a second time, missed the jQuery tag on the question, so now I've added a jQuery option.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No, I want to while page is loading src in img will be changed by script

Comment: @Masiama: When what page is loading? The page these links are on?

Comment: @Masiama: I've updated the answer anyway, you might want to take a look.